# How to disappear sidemenu without button in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, side-menu

I have some question. i made side menu in swift4.

when i clicked button, side menu appear and disappear.

but i want make disappear side menu without button.

for example, when i clicked another view (not side menu), disappear sidemenu.

my code like this.

```
class ContainerVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var constaint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var sideMenuOpen = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,  selector: #selector(toggleSideMenu), name: NSNotification.Name("ToggleSideMenu"), object: nil)
}

@objc func toggleSideMenu(){

    if sideMenuOpen {

        sideMenuOpen = false
        constaint.constant = -130

    }else {
        sideMenuOpen = true
        constaint.constant = 0

    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3){
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

[image]

when i click white background (view) , disappear side menu.
Thanks.

Comment: Use delegate method.

Comment: You can use a tap gesture

Comment: Use swipe gestures.

Comment: 1. Using swipe gesture 2. When side menu is open add a tap gesture to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code something like that, please add following code in viewDidLoad()

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismiss(fromGesture:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Then create a function for dismiss

```
@objc func OpenSideMenu(){
    sideMenuOpen = true
    constaint.constant = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3){
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

@objc func closeSideMenu(){
    sideMenuOpen = false
    constaint.constant = -130
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3){
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

@objc func dismiss(fromGesture gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    closeSideMenu()
}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Yes what is the question?

Comment: Thanks your advice. but i have some question.
when i click white page, disappear side menu. 
but , when one more clicked button, appear side menu ..

Comment: Then what do you want? Please explain more

Comment: I just want disappear side menu. not appear side menu. 
i mean when i clicked white back ground, disappear side menu , 
i want only appear side menu about button

Comment: Its very simple, just create a separate two functions for hiding and opening the side menu. Call first open function to show menu and call hiding function on tapping white background. Simple